# Passing pointer of object (which is created before ) to extern "C" function of dynamic shared library

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries

Example

I have 2 two files compiled together:

1. *MyClass.h / cpp* which contain data and function members;
2. *Main.cpp* which contains `int main()` and will load a dynamic library that was compiled from the source below;

==== Compile as dynamiclib.so=========

1. *dynamic.c* which has *extern "C" functionOfDynamic(MyClass*)*

---

Scenario

In the file `main.cpp` I will load (`dopen(dynamic.so,....)`) a dynamic library (that was compiled from `dynamic.c`), and one of its functions will be called and be passed a `MyClass` pointer.

My question: Can the function from the dynamic library call member functions of `MyClass`?

## dynamic.c

```
#include "MyClass.h"

int SomeMethodWrapper(void *A){

     return static_cast<MyClass*>(A)->SomeMethod();  // got core dump
}

extern "C" int functionOfDynamic(void* A) {
    SomeMethodWrapper(A);
}
```

I got core dump

Note: MyClass object  was created before loading "dynamiclib.so"

========Update==============

Dear All

The code above should be fine , I got core dump because I put something wrong , sorry

Comment: Looks fine. Try it and see where you get stuck.

Comment: The dynamic library will of course need access to the header file where MyClass is declared.

Comment: In my earlier comment (meanwhile deleted) I hadn't realized that the dynamic library is apparently entirely written in C. It's not quite clear to me how exactly you want to call member functions from there. Is that what you question is actually about... how to call C++ member functions from C code?

Comment: @jogojapan , I got core dump when calling A->SomeMethod()

Comment: Core dump? You mean your app crashes? Maybe show us the piece of code from within you call functionOfDynamic(). In general your code should work, but maybe something's going wrong with your pointer after you pass it to function.

Comment: Why is `dynamic.c` called `.c` although it's implemented in C++? And why C-linkage? The only type of pointer it will ever be passed are pointers to C++ objects, right?

Comment: Yes you can use the letter W in your identifiers and the digit 7 in your numbers. You can also call member functions across DSO boundaries. A language that can't do either of these things would be terminally stupid and no one in their right mind would be using it. Your core dump is yours. Fire up a debugger and solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have

`MyClass.h` / `MyClass.cpp` implementing

```
class MyClass {
public:
     //...
     void Foo( void );
;
```

Then you create your instance in `Main.cpp`, on which you call your DLL.

So how does this look on the DLL side? If you compile your DLL to call `MyClass::Foo`, and if you include `MyClass.cpp` in your DLL-project also (which you must, otherwise its unresolved external compile error), then you essentially compile `void Foo( void )` twice which sounds like a problem to me.

Instead, you should use an interface declaration:

`IMyClass.h`

with

```
struct IMyClass {
    virtual void Foo( void ) = 0;
}
```

and accordingly in the `MyClass.h`

```
class MyClass : public IMyClass;
```

so that you can call `Foo` (which is pure virtual) from your DLL without the actual implementation of the function. This works and regardless of the C or C++. Hope this helps.

Comment: I only include MyClass.h when compiling dynamic.c as dynamic-shared library

Comment: So you basically export your class definition from your executable? It is possible, sure. The C struct you need anyway if you want to keep dynamic.c really C.